# Netty 3.10.5-final "lags"

Tags: java, network-programming, netty

I'm using Netty 3.10.5-final for my network server. Server has about ~100 simultaneous clients.
Sometimes server starts to "lags", he stops sending packets, but continue to accept incoming connections.
This is the code i'm using to start server:

```
public class ClientListener {
/**
 * NIO server that processes requests between login and game servers.
 */
protected NettyServer gameServerListener;
/**
 * Client packets executor.
 */
protected final Executor packetsExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2);
ExecutorService bossExec = new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(1, 400000000, 2000000000, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
ExecutorService ioExec = new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(4 , 400000000, 2000000000, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

private String serverName;
private String bindIp;
private int port;

public ClientListener(String serverName, String bindIp, int port) {
    this.serverName = serverName;
    this.bindIp = bindIp;
    this.port = port;
}

public void start() {
    gameServerListener = new NettyServer(serverName, bindIp, port);
    gameServerListener.setChannelFactory(new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(bossExec, ioExec));
    gameServerListener.setPipelineFactory(new ClientPipeline(packetsExecutor));
    gameServerListener.setOption("child.bufferFactory", new HeapChannelBufferFactory(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN));
    gameServerListener.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);
    gameServerListener.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
    gameServerListener.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);
    gameServerListener.setOption("readWriteFair", true);
    gameServerListener.startServer();
}
```

NettyServer class is simple wrapper for ServerBootstrap.

First of all i thought that maybe IO Executer reached events/memory limits, and replaced its limits with 0, which means no limits at all. This doesn't solved problem.
Then i tried to use different executors for client packets, and that doesn't helped too.
My channel implementation extends SimpleChannelHandler and haven't any synchronization inside, so i threw away this version too.
I haven't ideas what else could cause this "lags", help needed.

Comment: Did you attach a profiler and check that the IO threads are not blocked ?

Comment: @NormanMaurer Yes, i attached profiler. Now i could see that i used to call database operations in the messageReceived method in the ChannelHandler. When database was performing long queries - this could block IO thread i guess. For now seems that everything is fine, continuing profiling.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution.

The problem was because i used to call database operations in the channelDisconnected method in the ChannelHandler. When database was performing long queries - this could block IO threads, and network start to lags.

So, in my case i just excluded all database operation outside of IO threads and that helped.